# Why is my IOS app's Display Name not respecting the en-AU localisation in InfoPlist.strings?

Tags: ios, localization, plist

I'm not able to get the display name of the application to identify that it should be using the `en-AU` InfoPlist file. It is always showing the plain `en` version.

I've created localized versions of the file, and have verified the value showing is from the `en` file. (I also have a Swedish version in an `sv` file, which shows the display name correctly.)

I have removed the `CFBundleName` entry, and set the `LSHasLocalizedDisplayName` value to `YES` in the Info.Plist file.

I have also included a Localizable.strings file for display values within the app, and they display from the appropriate en and en-AU sets correctly. It is just the display name that is oblivious to it's `en-AU` counterpart. Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only localize the "language" and not the "locale" for the display name (and maybe even more from InfoPlist.strings).

Comment: You could be right, but it would seem to be a lost opportunity.